# Simple script run via cronjob doesn't work but works from shell

Tags: bash, cron, cpanel

I am on shared hosting and I'm trying to schedule cronjob to run every now and then. Via cPanel I scheduled to execute my script but even though that according to my host support the cronjob runs, the script doesn't seem as doing anything. The cron job command I set via cPanel is:

```
/bin/sh /home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh
```

and the `cronjob2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/node_modules/forever/bin/forever stop 0
```

when via SSH I execute:

```
/home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh
```

it stops forever process as needed. From cronjob doesn't do anything.

How can I get this working?

EDIT:

So I've tried:

```
/bin/sh /home1/username/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh >> /tmp/mylog 2>&1
```

and `mylog` entries say:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

It seems that forever needs to run node and this cannot be found. How would I possibly fix this?

EDIT2:

Accepted answer at superuser.com. Thank you all for help
https://superuser.com/questions/763261/simple-script-run-via-cronjob-doesnt-work-but-works-from-shell/763288#763288

Comment: Could you go through the [Debugging Crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) guide and report your findings?

Answer (score 1):

For cron job lines in a crontab it's not required to specify kind of shell or e.g. of perl.
It's enough, that your script contains
[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) 
line.
Therefore you should remove /bin/sh from your cron job line.

Another aspect, that might cause a different behavior of your script by interactive start and by cron daemon start is possible different environment, first of all the PATH variable. Therefore check, if you script is able to be executed in very restricted environment, that is provided by cron daemon. You can determine your cron job environment experimentally by start of temporary cron job, that executes "env" command and writes its output to a file.

Once more aspect: Have you redirected STDOUT and STDERR of the cron job to a log file and read its content to analyze the issue? You can do it as follows:

```
 your_cron_job   >/tmp/any_name.log  2>&1
```

Comment: Remove /bin/sh from cron job line in the cron table. Determine location of bash using command "type -a bash" and possibly correct the shebang line in your shell script (cronjob2.sh). And by the way, execute "type sh" interactively too.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you wrote, when you run your script via SSH, you are using `bash`, because this line is the first of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

However, in the crontab, you are forcing the use of `sh` instead of `bash`. Are you sure your script is fully compatible with `sh`? Otherwise, simply replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` in your `cron` command and test again.